# Print specific elements of dict based on user input?

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

I'm creating a vehicle rental program, I have a dictionary containing cars.

```
car_dict = {'Sports': {'Audi': 'TT', 'Ferrari':'Spider'}, 
           'Luxry': {'Mercedes':'S-Class','Rollys Royce':'Phantom'},
```

I have two loops to print but one is using user input and the other is not - I need to combine them, effectively, to display which category the user picks, so if they type "Sports", it shows

```
Category chosen: 
--Sports--
>Audi TT
>Ferrari Spider
```

But right now, my two loops

```
 u_input = input("Enter >> ")
    if u_input in car_dict:
        try:
            print("Category chosen: ", car_dict[u_input])
        except KeyError:
            print("Not an existing category, sorry.")

 for key, value in car_dict.items():
        if key == 'Sports':
            print("--", key, "Cars --")
            for pair in value.items():
                print(*pair)
```

they print differently and I need a combination of both? If that makes sense. Currently, loop 1 displays

```
Category chosen:  {'Audi': 'TT', 'Ferrari': 'Spider'}
```

and loop 2,

```
--Sports--
Audi TT
Ferrari Spider
```

The latter NOT taking input.
How would I get around this? Take user input and display the matching category like the second loop. I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: Your data structure seems very limiting. For each category, you only allow one model from each manufacturer. What if Audi has more than one sports car?

Comment: @Barmar Yes that's true. However, I do have more to add in & will allow users to add. I just haven't done it yet, this was just to test :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for the second loop, just use the element selected using the user input.

```
u_input = input("Enter >> ")
if u_input in car_dict:
    print(f"Category chosen:\n--{u_input}--")
    for make, model in car_dict[u_input]:
        print(f'>{make} {model}')
else:
    print("Not an existing category, sorry.")
```